# Modify Wiley wileySev.cls for spanish

Tags: templates, spanish

I-ve been using LaTeX for over 10 years, but only basic out-of-the-box stuff. I am now setting up a book I wrote in spanish and I want to use Wiley's template.  However, I need to modify the wileySev.cls file so that chapters are named "Capítulo" instead of Chapter, and that the headings say "Prefacio" rather than "Preface".  I looked at the cls file and thought that just changing the following lines would do the trick>

```
\newcommand{\contentsname}{CONTENTS}
\newcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
\newcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de Cuadros}
\newcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografia}
\newcommand{\indexname}{INDEX}
\newcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\newcommand{\tablename}{Cuadro}
\newcommand{\partname}{PART}
\newcommand{\chaptername}{Capitulo}
\newcommand{\appendixname}{Apendice}
```

but that had no effect at all.

I was wondering if it would be a simple task to change the "cls" file or is it a better idea to start modifying the *memoir* book from scratch?

Can someone help me understand what needs to be changed in the "cls" file in order to make it spanish compatible?  I tried to understand it, but the language is just too complex for me.

Thanks for any suggestion.

The wiley template can be found here> http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wiley-book-style

Eric,

Comment: Are you loading `babel` with the `spanish` option?

Comment: If the answer is yes, then the module provides a simple mechanism to change the predefined names, prepending "spanish" to the standard names, as in 
`\newcommand{\spanishcontentsname}{CONTENTS}
\newcommand{\spanishlistfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
\newcommand{\spanishlisttablename}{Lista de Cuadros}`

Comment: It's very peculiar that the class defines `\chaptername`, but then uses an explicit `CHAPTER` string in `\@makechapterhead`.

Comment: Yes, I added babel from the beginning and I also tried to redefine the langue in very aspect. It did't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, there's no way to use the class with languages different from English, without *extensive* work. It uses several `\font` declarations and the same happens in the accompanying `w-bookps.sty` file.

This is due to the fact that Wiley uses proprietary fonts for the final printout. Accents are ***all*** wrong or swallowed.

There are other horrible features in the class. For instance, besides defining `\chaptername`, the class hardwires “CHAPTER” in the definition of `\@makechapterhead`, so no matter how you redefine `\chaptername` it will have no effect. Similarly, the definition of `\listoffigures` is

```
\newcommand{\listoffigures}{%
\startonoddpage
\global\titletrue
    \chapter*{List of Figures
        \@mkboth{\uppercase{List of Figures}}{\uppercase{List of Figures}}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{schapter}{List of Figures}
\vskip-9pt
\bgroup\parskip=2pt
{\def\numberline##1{\def\one{##1}%
\hb@xt@\@tempdima{\expandafter\splitintwo\one*\hfil}}
\normalsize\tocfonts
\hyphenpenalty=10000
    \@starttoc{lof}%
}
```

and you can clearly see that “List of Figures” is hardwired.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I was able to get a working copy by modifying these "hardwired" definitions. For example in the above example, in the fifth and following lines you change  `\uppercase{Lista de Figuras}` and also change it on line 693 for chapter. So basically I hardwired the names into spanish.  I also had to change fonts in the sty file to get accents to print correctly. For example helvetica had to be redefined from ` \def\helvetica{phvr} ` to `\def\helvetica{phvr8t}`.  That made it work.  Don't know if this is going to break later, but it seems to be working now. Thx